# Filtering for row-wise patterns in columns with a sequence of 0 and 1

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a way to filter/search for seqeuences/patterns in rows in a data frame that looks like this:

```
sensor               A  B  C  D  E  F
date
2011-11-02 19:22:32  0  0  0  0  1  0
2011-11-02 19:29:18  0  0  0  0  1  0
2011-11-02 19:29:30  0  0  1  0  1  0
2011-11-02 19:29:34  0  0  1  1  1  0
2011-11-02 19:29:35  0  0  1  1  0  0
2011-11-02 19:30:06  0  0  1  0  0  0
2011-11-02 19:30:10  0  0  1  0  1  0
2011-11-02 19:30:46  0  0  0  0  1  0
2011-11-02 19:31:25  0  0  1  0  1  0
2011-11-02 19:31:26  0  0  1  0  0  0
2011-11-02 19:31:31  0  0  1  1  0  0
2011-11-02 19:31:41  0  0  0  1  0  0
```

I need to now in which timeframes the sensors (A,B,C,..) were active (value == 1). E.g. for sensor C there are two intervals:

1. start: 2011-11-02 19:29:30, end: 2011-11-02 19:30:46
2. start: 2011-11-02 19:31:25, end: 2011-11-02 19:31:41

So:
0 -> 1: startdate and
1 -> 0: enddate

My first solution was to iterate over the rows. But since the real dataset is quite big, I was wondering if there is any way this can be done with pandas.

Thanks.

Comment: You say you want the periods when the sensors were active, but then you say `0->1` defines a startdate.  What about the first row in E?  Does that start a timeframe, even though there's no 0->1 transition, or is the only timeframe 19:30:10-19:31:26?

Comment: Columns starting with 1 (or ending with 1) can be considered as starting/ending there. Thanks for the answers so far. Both solutions work and are fast, but I think the one from @acushner is a bit more elegant. Any comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = {}
t = df - df.shift(1)
for col in df.columns:
    res[col] = t[col][t[col] != 0]
```

when a value for a particular column is 1, it means that the time frame has started, when it's -1, it means it's over

also, you could use a dict comprehension instead:

```
res = {col: t[col][t[col] != 0] for col in df.columns}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
col = df['A']
scol = col.shift()
starts = col & ~(scol == 1)
ends = ~(col == 1) & scol
if col[len(col)-1]:
    ends[len(ends)-1] = True
```

Then `starts` and `ends` will be two boolean series marking all start dates and end dates in the column 'A'.

The last two lines are for creating end dates that will be missing if a column ends like `... 1 1`. Also, if the column begins with `1 1 ...` (as DSM stated in the question's comments), a start date will be created.