# Filtering for row-wise patterns in columns

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow-up to question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511109/filtering-for-row-wise-patterns-in-columns-with-a-sequence-of-0-and-1). I opened another question, since the other one is 3 months old and answered.

Out of this df

```
sensor               A  B  C  D  E  F
date
2011-11-02 19:22:32  0  0  0  0  1  0
2011-11-02 19:29:18  0  0  1  0  0  0
2011-11-02 19:29:30  0  0  1  0  0  0
2011-11-02 19:29:34  0  0  1  0  0  0
2011-11-02 19:29:35  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-11-02 19:30:06  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-11-02 19:30:10  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-11-02 19:30:46  0  0  0  0  1  0
2011-11-02 19:31:25  0  0  1  0  1  0
2011-11-02 19:31:26  0  0  1  0  0  0
2011-11-02 19:31:31  0  0  1  1  0  0
2011-11-02 19:31:41  0  0  0  1  0  0
```

I want to build a df containing the start and end date for each period where one of the sensors (A,B,C) was active (i.e. value == 1).

In contrast to the other question, a sensor isn't inactive when its value returns to 0. It is active until another sensor value switches to 1 after itself switched to 0.

So in the above example, C is active from 19:29:18 to 19:30:46 (when D becomes active).

The result should look something like this:

```
df        start                   end                sensor
0     2011-11-02 19:29:18   2011-11-02 19:30:46        C
1     2011-11-02 19:31:25   2011-11-02 19:31:31        C
....
```

I can do this via loops on the data itself, or via loops on the dictionary that I get via the [answer of the old question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26514056/4170545), but I'm wondering if theres a better/faster solution with pandas.